# Own DbConfiguration for each DbContext - EntityFramework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two projects with their own `DbContext`. One references the other so I can use both databases. I want to load a seperate `DbConfiguration` for each `DbContext` but I am getting the following error:

> An instance of 'MontageplanungDbConfiguration' was set but this type
> was not discovered in the same assembly as the
> 'MontagesteuerungEntities' context. Either put the DbConfiguration
> type in the same assembly as the DbContext type, use
> DbConfigurationTypeAttribute on the DbContext type to specify the
> DbConfiguration type, or set the DbConfiguration type in the config
> file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more
> information.

I followed all the steps the link provided but it does not seem to work. See my code.

**First Project which references the other**

```
namespace Montageplanung
{
    internal class MontageplanungDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration 
    {
        public MontageplanungDbConfiguration()
        {
            SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
            SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("mssqllocaldb"));
        }
    }
}

namespace Montageplanung
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MontageplanungDbConfiguration))]
    public class MontageplanungEntities : DbContext
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Second project which is referenced by the first**

```
namespace MontagesteuerungDatabase.Utility
{
    internal class DatabaseConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public DatabaseConfiguration()
        {
            SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => 
                new ExecutionStrategy(10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
        }
    }
}

namespace MontagesteuerungDatabase
{

    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(DatabaseConfiguration))]
    public partial class MontagesteuerungEntities
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It looks like no second `DbConfiguration` can be loaded after the first `DbConfiguration` has been loaded. No matter if it is a different `DbContext`.